# Compiling Multiple C++, getting uninitialized Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, glm-math

Rather than have all my code in one giant file, I'm splitting it up into multiple files. The idea is to have a vector of structs (Thing) in another file (World.cpp), and to be able to access them from Main.cpp. Below is the relevant code:

World.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Lab4.h"
using namespace std;

struct Thing {
   glm::vec3 pos;
};

void InitWorld();
void addThingToWorld(glm::vec3 Position);
Thing getThingAtIndex(int index);
```

World.cpp:

```
#include "World.h"

vector<Thing> world;

void InitWorld() {
    Thing t;
    t.pos = glm::vec3 (0.5, 0.0, 0.0);
    world.push_back(t);
}

void addThingToWorld(glm::vec3 Position) {
   Thing t;
   t.pos = Position;
   world.push_back(t);
}

Thing getThingAtIndex(int index) {
   world.at(index);
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Lab4.h"

void main() {
    InitWorld();
    Thing t = getThingAtIndex(0);
    prinf("%f %f %f\n", t.pos.x, t.pos.y, t.pos.z);
}
```

The problem is that the values printed out from main are either garbage or all zeros. The code works perfectly fine if I have it in one file. I've spent a few hours on this but I can't figure it out. I would like an explanation as to why the "world" vector doesn't print out "0.5 0.0 0.0".

Comment: Please give us real code. `initWorld()` doesn't call the function `InitWorld()`.

Comment: `Thing t = new Thing();` wouldn't compile.

Comment: Why don't you consider encapsulating your world vector?

Comment: You still have some typos, t.Position...,  and there is no return in getThingAtIndex function.

Comment: @0x499602D2
I fixed the initWorld() line. I'm afraid the real code wouldn't be as helpful because they contain a lot of irrelevant details.

Comment: Try. return world.at(index);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't return anything in

```
Thing getThingAtIndex(int index) {
   world.at(index);
}   // returns garbage !!
```

Please correct in:

```
Thing getThingAtIndex(int index) {
   return world.at(index);
}   // now returns something
```

Comment: That was the reason, thank you so much! I've been using another language lately that doesn't require a return statement so I subconsciously forgot to put one there.